# can't convert uint8 to uint8 to republish a field from a message

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This might sound like a really silly question but I've been trying to figure out the answer for the last two hours. :(
I have a Message that includes a `uint8` field.  In the callback that receives that message, I need to republish it after performing a calculation.  I'm using a temporary variable, that is of the same class as the callback message type, and the republished message is a simple std_msgs::UInt8.

```
nxt::LegoNXTROS_Status currStatus;

void statusCallBack(const nxt::LegoNXTROS_Status::ConstPtr& msg) {
    currStatus.leftMotorEncoder = msg->leftMotorEncoder;
    currStatus.rightMotorEncoder = msg->rightMotorEncoder;
    currStatus.sonarSensor = msg->sonarSensor;
    currStatus.leftTouchSensor = msg->leftTouchSensor;
    currStatus.rightTouchSensor = msg->rightTouchSensor;
    std_msgs::UInt8 perturbedmsg = currStatus.sonarSensor; <<ERROR HERE
    pWhiteNoiseAdder.publish(perturbedmsg);
}

sWhiteNoiseAdder = nWhiteNoiseAdder.subscribe("LegoNXTROS_Status", 1000, statusCallBack);
pWhiteNoiseAdder = nWhiteNoiseAdder.advertise<std_msgs::UInt8>("PerturbedSonar",10);
```

Message Definition below:

```
# LegoNXTROS_Status message
# Defines the protocol for publishing the NXT robot's status.
#
uint16 leftMotorEncoder
uint16 rightMotorEncoder
uint8 sonarSensor
bool leftTouchSensor
bool rightTouchSensor
```

Could someone please help me through this?
Cheers,
Nap

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197038/can%27t-convert-uint8-to-uint8-to-republish-a-field-from-a-message./) by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on ROS Answers with karma: 302 on 2014-11-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From message definition http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/std_msgs/html/msg/UInt8.html

```
std_msgs::UInt8 perturbedmsg;
perturbedmsg.data = currStatus.sonarSensor;
```

---

Originally posted by [kmhallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3102/kmhallen/) with karma: 1416 on 2014-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on 2014-11-08**:
Thank you for both the answer and the link.